# GCM CCS XMPP on Google Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use GCM CCS via XMPP protocol. I have been looking around for any documentation on whether it is supported on GAE or not. However not able to find anything good on it.

I found some links mentioning  that CCS XMPP is not allowed on GAE, which were posted before the latest GCM release. I am wondering if anything has changed with the latest release.

Appengine does have an XMPP api, but doesn't seem to have any reference other than using with something like Google Talk.

Anyone with any idea regarding this or any pointers, please help!

Comment: Here's a template for Gradle cloud endpoint module with detailed information. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints

Comment: @KayAnn, thanks for your response. I may be overlooking but couldn't find anywhere in the sample code reference to working with XMPP from an appengine backend.